# Various System.OperationCanceledException exceptions happening on my Azure Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, webapi, azure-appservice

I have a .Net 6 Web API hosted on Azure App Service.
When I look at the Application Insight logs, I see a number of 500 Exceptions of this type:

> System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled.

This happens on various API endpoints. The stack trace looks like this:

```
System.OperationCanceledException:
   at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowOperationCanceledException (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Threading.SemaphoreSlim+<WaitUntilCountOrTimeoutAsync>d__31.MoveNext (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1+<GetConfigurationAsync>d__24.MoveNext (Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols, Version=6.10.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler+<HandleAuthenticateAsync>d__6.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer, Version=6.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
```

I guess this is happening when the front-end (which is an Angular web app, but could also be Postman) makes a request to the API, and for whatever reason, cancels the request before it is complete.

Can I simply ignore these errors? Should I be handling them somehow? (And if I should, how should I do so). Is my API perhaps crashing (and restarting) every time this happens, as it is an unhandled error?

Thanks

EDIT: Here is the code in my Startup.cs regarding JwtBearer, which is implicated in the stack trace. You will notice there is a section that deals with a SignalR Core chat hub, which is used by my API:

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = $"https://{Configuration["Auth0:Domain"]}/";
                options.Audience = Configuration["Auth0:Audience"];
                options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                {
                    OnMessageReceived = context =>
                    {
                        StringValues accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];

                        // If the request is for our SignalR hub...
                        PathString path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken) &&
                            (path.StartsWithSegments("/chatHub")))
                        {
                            // Read the token out of the query string
                            context.Token = accessToken;
                        }
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };
            });
```

Comment: Please show your code about `JwtBearerOptions` in your Program.cs file.

Comment: Thanks @Jason I have edited my post to include the requested code.

Comment: @FabricioRodriguez I've been experiencing the same thing since May 25/26th when this started happening after no changes to my site. Has this been your experience?

Comment: Hi @ajbeaven it's been happening for a while actually. Definitely not a new thing. I haven't found a solution yet, but to be honest, I haven't put too much effort into it either. I've had the flu for the past week, so I haven't been firing on all cylinders lately... Will hopefully give it more attention when I feel better again.

Comment: @FabricioRodriguez - no worries, just thought I'd check. Your issue might be related to this: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/38467. Looks like it's expected. Check for cases where your clients might be explicitly aborting a request e.g. find-as-you-type controls which abort if you continue typing into the search bar. This problem is only related to the JwtBearerHandler insofar as it happens to be the first thing in the pipeline that calls ThrowIfCancellationRequested on the cancellationToken passed through.

Comment: Thanks @ajbeaven. Ok, that makes a lot of sense - I understand now why the exception is happening on JwtBearerHandler. I will read the link you provided shortly. Thanks!